# Google Analytics Is Not Collecting Data

Tags: google-analytics

I have had this problem since early December and can’t work out why. 
I received this message in the Analytics Notifications

"Property Recipe Pocket is not receiving hits"

My site is www.recipepocket.com

I have tried to work this out by myself but just can’t figure it out. 
What I have done over the course of the last month:

1. Removed old code and added it back, that didn’t work
2. Removed the above code from the site and tried using the Google Tag Manager, that doesn't work either.
3. I have recently re-added the gtag.js code and still no luck.

Could anyone help me with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You missed `||`, see the first line:

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
gtag('js', new Date());
gtag('config', 'UA-122296184-1');
```